# How safe is the Apache folder password protection?

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

How safe is the Apache folder password protection? Of course, safety is relative and depending on other variables, like the rest of the server and so on.

But zoomed in on only the folder protection in .htaccess: Is this a safe way? Are there known big holes?

Answer (score 5):

I assume you're referring to the `AuthType` set of directives for creating a password protected directory.

There's a few things you can do to make it *"safer"*.

1. User DIGEST method instead of BASIC for the `AuthType`. BASIC authentication passes the username and password as a base64 encoded string. DIGEST uses a nonce and MD5 so the actual password is never transmitted.
2. Make sure your htpasswd/htdigest file is NOT within the web document root, otherwise it may be possible that someone can access it through apache (e.g. `http://example.com/.htpasswd`)
3. If you *must* use BASIC auth, considering using SSL
4. Unlike session based authentication, a user who logs in will stay logged in until the browser is closed. There's no session timeout. Not much you can do about this except maybe forcing a 401/403 to trick the browser into thinking its auth is incorrect

Additional info: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html